# Environment shadows change with head movement

Tags: virtual-reality, google-vr, daydream

I am developing game for Daydream platform and i ran into problem when I test my app on android, it looks like shadows on environment are moving with head.

When I test this inside Unity editor, it looks perfectly fine, but when testing on android it looks like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfX_w7kmY3k

You have to focus on mountains in background where you can see shadows moving-
At first I thought its draw distance, but its still same when i give far clip on camera to 1000. And this still happens even if I remove all lights from scene.

I tried everything I could think of, but this is still my first project in Unity.
Any kind of hint would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change Quality Setting from Editor->Project Setting->Quality or Cascade Setting. Adjust according your requirements. Normal Quality Setting is set to Good but you can change Cascade Setting.

[image: Quality Setting and Cascade Setting Image For Help]